# choose folder with FileChooser

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

i want to add kivy filechooser into gridlayout
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html

i have my main class :

```
class MainApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        mylayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
```

i want to add editor class in filechooser into mylayout BoxLayout
if i add

```
mylayout.add_widget(Editor.run())
```

I have filechooser in fullscreen of my window, not in boxlayout

I want that user can choose folder (not file).

Comment: Do you want to add the FileChooser or the Editor?

Comment: I want to add "FileChooser"
i want that user can choose folder (not file)

Comment: if you check Editor is not a widget but the application of the example, so that is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Add `dirselect: True` into FileChooserListView / FileChooserIconView

```
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooserlistview
            dirselect: True
            path:
                filechooserlistview.path
```

[FileChooser Controller » dirselect](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.dirselect)

> ```
> dirselect
> ```
>
> Determines whether directories are valid selections or not.
>
> dirselect is a BooleanProperty and defaults to False.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have found solution but i have empty pop up :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

import os


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()


class Editor(App):
    pass

import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        root=Root()
        root.show_load()
        layout.add_widget(root)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image]

why i have not folder in pop up ?